# Getting error status trying to upload my kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, kubernetes-health-check

I have my controller.yaml that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: hmrcaction
  labels:
    name: hmrcaction
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: hmrcaction
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: hmrcaction
        version: 0.1.4
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hmrcaction
        image: ccc-docker-docker-release.someartifactory.com/hmrcaction:0.1.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: fff-artifactory
```

and service yaml that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hmrcaction
  labels:
    name: hmrcaction
spec:
  # if your cluster supports it, uncomment the following to automatically create
  # an external load-balanced IP for the frontend service.
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 9000
  selector:
    name: hmrcaction
```

and I have a kubernetes cluster, so I wanted to use this rc to upload my docker to the cluster and I did it like this:

```
kubectl create -f controller.yaml
```

but I get some weird status, when I run the command `kubectl get pods` I get:

```
NAME               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hmrcaction-k9bb6   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          40s
```

what is this?? before the status was `ErrImagePull`...

please help :)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl describe pods -l name=hmrcaction` should give you more useful information.